# Assigning generated str to an object

Tags: python

```
def animalfunc():
    dog='nonkey'
    cat= [12,3,4]
    goat = cat.append(2)
    vars()[dog]=goat
    return nonkey
animalfunc()
```

Why is this flagging an error? this is a simplified version of the issue I have with a data frame on pyspark.
I assign a generated str to a dataframe.
Python knows the str exists and that dog var here exists, and vars()[dog] exists when called. In the data frame what's more confusing is it works for the first part of the loop and then randomly forgets the str I'm assigning exists. Can anyone shed some light on this?
Error: name 'nonkey' is not defined.

```
name_list=['charlie', 'grimjaw']

string= name_list[0] + '_' + name_list[1]

vars()[string] = dataframe.unionByName(dataframe2)
```

This is the higher level example of what I'm trying to do.
Name Error: name 'charlie_grimjaw' is not defined

Comment: `goat = cat.append(2)` will set `goat` to None.  Is this what you intended or did you want to set it to the updated list?

Comment: update. What is the logic behind this, append adds to a list so why would it set goat to none?

Comment: @CAOB1 - the `append` method simply adds the object to the specified list and does not return anything. it's an inplace update.

Comment: @CAOB1 You have used the assignment operator in your code above to assign the result of `cat.append(2)` to `goat`.  Since the append method adds `2` to the list (referenced by the variable `cat`) and returns `None`, the variable `goat` will be set to `None`.

Comment: @Prins so how do I do what I want to do? assign the string to cat.append(2)

Comment: @CAOB1 In your example, you will simply have `vars()[dog] = cat`.

Comment: @Prins returns an error. nonkey not defined

Comment: @CAOB1 The error is due to the last line in your function which should be `return dog` since there is no variable called `nonkey`.

Comment: @Prins return dog outputs 'nonkey'.....I want to return the object goat/cat.append(2) with the name nonkey. I want to call nonkey and get the output cat.append(2). Or in other words I want to call the generated string name in the second example and get the data frame.unionbyname result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247487/discussion-between-prins-and-c-a-ob1).

Comment: `string` is a built-in Python module. Maybe not the best name for a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a detailed answer based on what I stated in the [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/55110421#55110421).

Firstly, the example function in your post incorrectly sets `goat` to the result of `cat.append(2)` which would be `None`. You can correct this by using `cat` directly.

Secondly, the [vars()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars) function can take an argument which is a dictionary-type object.

If you call `vars()` with no arguments then it will work similarly to [locals()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals), that is, it will give you access to the local variables.  This means if you set a variable using vars() inside a function then it will create a local variable that is destroyed when the function finishes executing. You can solve this in several ways including:

1. use [globals](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals)
2. return the key and data in a suitable data structure.
3. create a global data structure and use it in the function

Here is your function implemented correctly using globals:

```
def animal_func():
    dog = 'nokey'
    cat = [12, 3, 4]
    globals()[dog] = cat
    return dog
    
animal_func()

# display global variables (can also use vars() here)
print(globals())
```

Answer (score 0):

Cannot dynamically generate variables inside a function in python. I instead return a dictionary with the output data frame and a dynamically generated string.

Comment: Please see my answer in the chat and above.  You can create variables inside a function. They will have local scope and will be destroyed once the function has finished executing. One approach is to use `globals()` as described in my answer.